# I can not filter things by attribute values in iot core

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-iot-core, aws-iam-policy

I have a problem regarding the filtering things by attribute name and attribute value via aws cli.

I have two different environments and I am able to use the following cli commands in one of from them succesfully as below:

```
aws iot list-things
aws iot list-things --attribute-name attName --attribute-value attValue
```

But the problem is that altough there are data on both environments, I get an empty array when I use the second cli command above. I am suspicious about the iam policy settings of two different environments but so far I am able to list all things in both environments. Which iam policy or what configuration can affect the filtering of iot core things? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have found the problem. The reason is that in one environment, all thing types are set as non-searchable. Therefore it is not possible to list non-searchable things. I recreated the things with type value as "searchable" and now I am able to list things.